# Como substituir caracteres digitados por asteriscos ao pedir input do usuário

Tags: python

Ao pedir entrada de dados do usuário, como fazer para trocar os caracteres digitados por asteriscos?

Tentei assim mas ele não mostra os caracteres:

```
import getpass
senha = getpass.getpass("Digite sua senha: ")
```

Comment: a função q usei não funcionou, alguem conhece uma mais recente?

Comment: Salve! O Stack Overflow não é uma plataforma para encomenda de código ou pedidos de solução de trabalhos acadêmicos, e sim de solução de problemas ou dúvidas concretos em código existente.

Comment: eu tenho 12 anos, não to na faculdade

Comment: @CésarRodriguez a pergunta do @007 parece estar dentro das normas, a pergunta apenas se refere a como exibir `*` no lugar dos caracteres para que não seja visível no terminal ou cmd o que o usuário estiver digitando. 007 no caso do getpass, se eu não me engano nada é mostrado, semelhante ao `sudo` em Linux, ao menos não em Windows (se for o seu caso).

Comment: Concordo, e eu não disse que está fora das normas -- só dei um feedback para algo que não demonstrou nenhum esforço de pesquisa, em vez de um downvote.

Answer (score 2):

A função [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) solicita uma senha do usuário sem emiti-la. O usuário é solicitado usando uma string como prompt, cujo padrão é 'Password: '. Essa função tenta emular o comportamento padrão de terminais Posix ao solicitar senhas do usuário que é não exibir os caracteres digitados e não caracteres de máscara.

```
import getpass

senha = getpass.getpass("Digite sua senha: ")

print(f"A senha digitada foi {senha}")
#Digite sua senha: 
#A senha digitada foi 123
```

Caso queira que os caracteres de máscara apareçam, você pode usar o módulo [PWInput](https://pypi.org/project/pwinput/) que permite entrada de senha exibindo uma máscara ao digitar.

```
import pwinput

senha = pwinput.pwinput(prompt='Digite sua senha: ')

print(f"A senha digitada foi {senha}")
#Digite sua senha: ***
#A senha digitada foi abc
```

Manipulando o parâmetro `mask` você pode trocar o asteriscos por outro caractere.

```
import pwinput

senha = pwinput.pwinput(prompt='Digite sua senha: ', mask='_')

print(f"A senha digitada foi {senha}")
#Digite sua senha: ___
#A senha digitada foi 789
```

A desvantagem do uso de mascara de digitação é que permite a um observador contar o número de caracteres contidos na senha.

<sup>Teste os exemplos no [replit.com](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/MidnightblueEthicalLoops#main.py)</sup>